# NSMutableUrlRequest eats plus signs

Tags: iphone, nsstring, nsdata, nsmutableurlrequest

I create NSMutableUrlRequest for sending data to server, add all necessary fields to it and then add the string for sending like this:

```
[theRequest setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

postString is a usual NSString.

The problem is, when I receive this request at the server, all the plus (+) signs disappear from the http body. So if I had "abcde+fghj" on iPhone, I get "abcde fghj" on the server".

Can this be some encoding problem from using dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding? Or some NSMutableUrlRequest stripping feature? What can I do to make it stop stripping plus signs? I need to receive UTF8 strings at the server side.

Answer (score 4):

The plus (+) sign is a [standard shortcut](http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/4_URI_Recommentations.html) for a space, in a URL's query string portion. If you want a literal +, encode it as %2b.

Comment: I don't dispute your answer, but shouldn't this only happen if the string is passed through the method `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` and not just by encoding it using UTF8?

Comment: thanks, now I figured it out. It seems I needed to run my string through the stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: first, then I needed to run it through replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%2B" and several more of those replaces for different characters, because stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: doesn't escape them all

Answer (score 0):

May be the server doesn't know which is the encoding of the POST body.
Have you tried to add the charset=UTF-8 into the header of your request like that:

```
[theRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

Comment: thanks, I had application/x-www-form-urlencoded, but didn't have charset=UTF-8, I added that too now

Comment: update: just adding "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" doesn't help, I still need to replace characters to % values, the whole POST body needs to be encoded heavily...

Answer (score 0):

For e.g. you need to post `data` to the backend with a `"Content-Type" -> "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`

> application/x-www-form-urlencoded: the keys and values are encoded in
>   key-value tuples separated by '&', with a '=' between the key and the
>   value. Non-alphanumeric characters in both keys and values are percent
>   encoded: this is the reason why this type is not suitable to use with
>   binary data (use multipart/form-data instead)

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST)

You can percent-encode your data by applying function `addingPercentEncoding` to your string in Swift:

```
guard let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)?.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .alphanumerics) else {
   failureCompletion()
   return
}

var request = URLRequest(url: url)
...
request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.httpBody = "jsonString".data(using: .utf8)
...
```